# What do you call it when someone reminds you of your ingratitude?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Adopted mother: 'Your parents died. I took you in. If I knew you'd steal from me, I would have left you to the State.'

Mother: 'If only I knew you'd turn out like this, I would have had an abortion.'

Comment: Embarrassing?  Don

Comment: In the case of your specific examples, "verbal abuse" or "emotional abuse" works too.

Comment: You were working as a waitress in a cocktail bar, when I met you.
I picked you out, I shook you up
And turned you around, turned you into someone new.

Now five years later on you've got the world at your feet.
Success has been so easy for you.
But don't forget it's me who put you where you are now,
And I can put you back there too. Don't, don't you want me?
You know I can't believe it
When I hear that you won't see me.

Comment: Tuesday​‌​‌​‌​‌.

Answer (score 30):

I believe that's called "guilt tripping" someone.

> "Guilt trip"
>
> VERB
>
> 1. make (someone) feel guilty, especially in order to induce them to do something:
>
>    Ex. "a pay increase will not guilt-trip them into improvements."
>
>    (Source: Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score 13):

**Shame** ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shaming))

> *n.* the painful feeling arising from the consciousness of something dishonorable, improper, ridiculous, etc.

In the example above, however, the mothers are using the verb

**Shaming**

> *v.* to cause to feel shame; make ashamed